# PageRequestManager error with UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel, postback

I'm using an update panel which updates when my timer ticks (1 sec.)

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="false"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="updTimer" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
            function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                document.getElementById('bottom').scrollIntoView();
            }
        </script>
        <asp:Timer ID="updTimer" runat="server" Interval="1000" ontick="updTimer_Tick" />
        <div style="overflow:auto; height:420px; width:100%;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblOutput" runat="server" />
            <div id="divLoading" runat="server"><img src="./Images/Loading.gif" width="50px" height="50px" alt="loading" /></div>
            <a id="bottom"></a>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I get this error on the page when it loads (and after loading from postback).

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Fri, 7 Mar 2014 16:40:37 UTC


Message: 'Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager' is null or not an object
Line: 59
Char: 17
Code: 0
```

What is causing the error?

Also, it seems to only happen when the web app is hosted by IIS (6)

Comment: Set `EnablePartialRendering` set to `true` to your script manager

Comment: well, that fixed that. Thanks.